# Does EnterpriseDB support Oracle RAC to Postgres replication?

Tags: oracle, replication, rac, enterprisedb

Does EnterpriseDB support Oracle RAC to Postgres replication?

Answer (score 2):

Originally a comment by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio):

> The difference between Oracle RAC and Postgres cluster architectures does not in itself prevent you from setting up replication between an Oracle database (RAC or no RAC) and a Postgres database (Advanced Server or not).